# Multiple threads to comunicate with multiple sensors

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to threads. I want to communicate with multiple sensors at one time after every minute continuously 24/7.

**Senario:**
I have a method to talk to the sensors which takes 3 arguments

```
public String perform(String command, String ip, String port)
{
  //talk to the sensor and then 
  returns reply;
}
```

I have a database that contains the details of the sensor.

**What I'm doing right now**

```
while(true)
{
  //get sensors from database

   //run perform method for all instruments
   for(int i=0;i<sensors.length-1;i++)
   {
    //call perform method and save the reply
   }
   Thread.sleep('one minute');
}
```

**Problem:**
The problem is if I have 100 sensors and each sensor takes 1 second to reply then after that I will be waiting for 1 minute, in this case I may lose some information. And to be honest sometime It takes more than a second to respond.

**What I want to do is**, get the information from the database for all the sensors
then create one thread for each sensor. Then run all the threads at one time which will return me some information. After that wait for one minute then do it again.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) ?

A simple usage would be to create a [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) for each of your sensors, and configure the thread pool to contain as many threads as you have sensors. Then submit each Callable, specifying an appropriate schedule.

Note that this approach doesn't guarantee particularly accurate timings (Java's not by any means a real-time platform). The other issue is that creating a lot of threads can be relatively memory-hungry (IIRC the standard heap allocation per thread is 512k, but it's configurable) and this approach wouldn't scale if you had 1000s of sensors.

Comment: This sounds good.  One comment I'd add is to _not_ schedule each of the sensors to fire at the same time.  If you schedule each sensor with an initial delay of 60000 / number of sensors milliseconds then that would use the minimal number of threads.  With 100 sensors, start the first one with a 0ms delay, 2nd one with a 600ms delay, 3rd 1200ms, etc..  This would use the fewest threads.  At the end of each poll, each sensor would resubmit itself with a 1 minute delay.

Comment: +1 for Callable and ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.  I would also recommend that you plan for timeouts and exceptions and how to treat them.  Don't neglect thread cancellation policies.

Comment: @Gray - staggering the sensor calls may well make sense. I guess it depends on whether the OP requires to grab data from all sensors at the same instant per minute, or whether some skew is acceptable

Comment: Agreed @Brian.  If they aren't going to be staggered then there needs to be some delay calculations when the jobs resubmit themselves to make sure they all fire on the minute.

Comment: Thanks for the response... Had a look into the ThreadPoolExecutor... and found some useful examples..... but I am not able to multiple threads dynamically....!!! How do I do this...???? please See my answer...

Comment: I am trying to do somthing like this                             for(int i=0;i<numberOfSensors;i++)
  {
   queue.add(new Runnable() {
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
     perform(arg1,arg2,arg3);
    }
   });
  }

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would take a different approach.  I would have the server always listening via a RESTful API and then have the sensors POST their state every minute (or other interval you decide).  This way the server and the sensors don't need to be within the same JVM and IMHO is more scalable.  Also, this way any sensor can also query for the state of any other sensor via  another RESTful API on the server.

Additionally the server can start a thread to handle each POST and if one sensor is taking very long, the others are not blocked.

Comment: This implies there is code running on each sensor.  The OP implies to me that it is just some sort of IP gateway to a sensor array.

Comment: Yes, true.  Perhaps it is simply another 'service' that knows how to interact with the sensor (think of a delegate)...

Comment: Thanks for your response...Server and sensors are not within the same JVM. And I cannot change the sensor, they are different devices which I do not have access to. I can only send a command to the sensor over the internet using a specific protocol which replies me in HEX codes and then I convert the values into readable form. So I cannot amend the sensor.

Comment: I would update your question to state such, I'll delete this answer.